# Menu list not showing in Safari/iOS

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I have a menu which is working perfectly in Chrome on Mac and Chrome on Android. But it doesn't work with Safari on Mac and Chrome/Safari on iOS.

The menu items is correctly showed in source code and I can see the elements correctly placed if I hover the code in a browser inspector. The problem is that they are not actually showed in the browsers. It is like they are laying under det rest of the elements. I have tried with z-index without any luck.

Any help is appriciated.

Ember

```
<div class="goodie-pack-menu">
  <button class="goodie-pack-menu-toggle" {{ action "toggleMenu" }}>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="goodie-pack-menu-list {{ if open 'goodie-pack-menu-list--open' }}">
    <li class="goodie-pack-menu-item" {{ action "setFilterId" null }}>{{ t 'generic.all' }}</li>
    {{#each goodiePack.menuItems as |menuItem| }}
      <li class="goodie-pack-menu-item" {{ action "setFilterId" menuItem.id }}>
        {{ menuItem.name }}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.goodie-pack-menu
  width: 100%
  height: 100%

  &-toggle
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    background: white
    border: none
    display: block
    z-index: 200000

  &-list
    position: fixed
    width: 100%
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    left: 0
    list-style: none
    background: #f9f9f9
    display: none    

    &--open
      display: block

  &-item
    padding: 20px 0
    text-align: center
    pointer-events: all
```

Comment: post CSS as well, or a working demo on JSfiddle or codepen

Comment: It should be there now. In .sass / ember format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting overflow: visible in my .large-header and then overflow: hidden in the container.

Answer (score 0):

Just add position to &-toggle:

```
&-toggle
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    background: white
    border: none
    position: relative
    display: block
    z-index: 200000
```

Comment: Did not do the trick :( 

The menu items actually works if i push where they are suppose to be. Perhaps that information could help you?

Comment: It seems that another class (.large-header) is "blocking" by having: overflow: hidden.

But the thing is that we use this for another thing where we display some informations in the header when scrolling a bit down.